# After spliting my c# project into two seperate projects, one project crashes without any exception. Might have something to do with different threads?

Tags: .net, winforms, sockets, asynchronous, crash

I am currently developing my first c# project, its a chat room application, in c# win forms with .net 7.0.
The user can create a chatroom and serve as a server, or simply join another chatroom.
For communication i use the socket class.

I started to build one project, but now the requirement is to have two seperate projects, which can run individually.
Right now i have 3 projects in my solution, one is the combined one, and the other two are the seperate projects for client and server.
The combined solutution is working as intended, same goes with the server project, but the client project crashes without throwing an exception.
Its the exact same code, and i dont understand why one runs fine, and the other simply closes.

I think i could identify the line of code that causes the crash, or at least thats the last line of code i can go to when going through every line of code in the debugger with pressing F10.
When i reach this line and press F10 to go to the next line, the application closes.

`var amountBytes = await _clientSocket.ReceiveAsync(bytes);`

This line of code sits inside a try block, and i dont reach the catch block, the application simply closes. The first go through of the while loop and the ReceiveAsync() is sucessful, and at the second round of the while loop it crashes at that exact line. But it only does so in the seperate client project, not in the combines project where the exact same code is.

The line of code sits in a Task i wrote to receive messages through the socket, this is the whole Task, the line of code is at the beggining of the task.

```
private async Task ReceiveMessagesAsync()
        {
            Byte[] bytes = new byte[1024];
            while (true)
            {
                if (_clientSocket != null && _clientSocket.Connected)
                {
                    try
                    {
                        //Receive
                        var amountBytes = await _clientSocket.ReceiveAsync(bytes);

                        //If Server closes, we get a nullbyte
                        if (amountBytes == 0)
                        {
                            //UI
                            SetStatusToDisconnected();
                            HideOwnNameLabel();
                            DisplayNotification("Server wurde geschlossen");

                            break;
                        }

                        string decodedMessage = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(bytes, 0, amountBytes);

                        //If we receive a message
                        if (decodedMessage.StartsWith(_messageIdentifyer))
                        {
                            string message = decodedMessage.Substring(_messageIdentifyer.Length);
                            //Prepare the datamodel
                            DataModel? messageModel = JsonSerializer.Deserialize<DataModel>             (message);
  
                            if (messageModel != null)
                            {
                                DisplayMessage(messageModel);
                            }
                        }

                        //If we receive the userlist
                        if (decodedMessage.StartsWith(_listIdentifyer))
                        {
                            _usersDictionary.Clear();

                            //Convert the long string to an Array
                            string[] tempArray = decodedMessage.Split(new[] { _listIdentifyer }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
                            string username = "";
                            int clientID = 0;
                            //we go through the loop with i +=2, since two following array item represent a single user.
                            for (int i = 0; i < tempArray.Length; i += 2)
                            {
                                clientID = Convert.ToInt32(tempArray[i]);
                                username = tempArray[i + 1];
                                //Dont add myself to the userlist
                                if (clientID != _personalId)
                                {
                                    _usersDictionary.Add(clientID, username);
                                }
                            }
                            //UI
                            DisplayOnlineClients();
                            PopulateListBox();
                        }
                    }
                    catch (Exception ex)
                    {

                        Console.WriteLine($"Client [{_personalId}]" + ex.Message);
                        //UI
                        DisplayNotification("Verbindung zum Server verloren");
                        HideOwnNameLabel();
                        SetStatusToDisconnected();
                        break;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
```

I am a beginner so let me explain my thought process:
I used a task because i dont want the UI to freeze while we wait for a message. Tasks will advise the threadpool to use any thread is whishes to work until it hits await, and resumes with any thread is whishes after the await result is there. If i didnt use Tasks, my application would freeze while i wait for a message.

I am abssolutely not sure, but something in my heads tells me it might be an unhandled exception that happens in a different thread, if that makes sense?

I tried to catch anything with this exception handler:

```
static void UnhandledExceptionHandler(object sender, UnhandledExceptionEventArgs e)
        {
            Exception exception = (Exception)e.ExceptionObject;

            // Log or handle the exception here
            Console.WriteLine("Unhandled Exception:");
            Console.WriteLine(exception.ToString());

        }
```

But that didnt help, the application simply closes, there is no error message in the console.

Another thing i found out:
The first time i hit the line we talk about `var amountBytes = await _clientSocket.ReceiveAsync(bytes);` it sucesfully receives data.
Right after that the connected attribute of the socket changes to false.
I did read about that, and from what i have read the connected attribute respresents the last state of the socket, and is uneliable. This is confusing to me, since i just sucesfully received something, and then it changes to false.

I am sitting on this problem for days now, and i cant find a solution anywhere, because my problem seems to be so special.

My stomach tells me it has something to do with the multiple threads, but that could be wrong, i am a beginner...

I would appreciate any help, whatever it is.
Thanks in advance.

Edit: I also tried to remove the if(socket.connected) condition at the beginning of the Task, didnt do anything.

Edit2: A community memeber asked for the method that calls ReceiveMessageAsync(), so i add it here:

```
public async Task ConnectAsync(string ipadress)
    {
        _clientForm.NotificationTextbox.Clear();

        try
        {
            //Create endpoint and socket
            _clientEndpoint = new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Parse(ipadress), _port);
            _clientSocket = new Socket(AddressFamily.InterNetwork, SocketType.Stream, ProtocolType.Tcp);

            //Connect
            await _clientSocket.ConnectAsync(_clientEndpoint!);

            byte[] tempbytes = new byte[1024];

            //Wait for ID from Server
            var receivedData = await _clientSocket.ReceiveAsync(tempbytes);

            string messageString = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(tempbytes, 0, receivedData);

            //Check if receivedData is indeed the ID
            if (messageString.StartsWith(_IDIdentifyer))
            {

                string[] parts = messageString.Split(new string[] { _IDIdentifyer }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
                _personalId = Convert.ToInt32(parts[0]);
                Console.WriteLine("Client hat ID erhalten:" + _personalId);

                //Send own Nickname to the Server                    
                tempbytes = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(_nicknameIdentifyer + _nickname!);
                await _clientSocket.SendAsync(tempbytes);

                //UI
                SetStatusToConnected();
                ConnectButtonLogic();
                DisplayOwnName();

                //Connection established now, received messages get handled in Task ReceiveMessages
                _ = ReceiveMessagesAsync();
            }
            else
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Failed to receive ID");
                //UI
                DisplayNotification("Konnte ID nicht beziehen, versuchen Sie es erneut.");
                SetStatusToDisconnected();
                HideOwnNameLabel();
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
            //UI
            SetStatusToDisconnected();
            HideOwnNameLabel();
        }
    }
```

EDIT: I found the solution, it was something clompletly else!

I am using win forms, and another form (which was the main form) called the current form where my code gets executed automaticaly by the load method when the new form sucesfully opened.
I was using `this.Close()` on the previous form, so my new form was getting closed after a very short time, and i thought my code is causing this.
I changed the line to `this.Hide()` and now it works. I guess its wise if i change it back to `this.Close()` and set the settings that the application shouldnt close when the mainForm closes, but instead if the last Form closes.

Comment: You haven't posted any UI updating code, but you might need to check if an invoke is required in all your UI update methods. If you try to update the UI from a thread it was not created on, that thread will simply terminate.  Also, after ```var amountBytes = await _clientSocket.ReceiveAsync(bytes);``` you report the socket is disconnected. Have you traced the code, and do you somehow execute ```SetStatusToDisconnected();```?

Comment: SetStatusToDisconnected is just UI stuff, so the user knows he is not connected anymore. I have a method that shotdowns and closes the socket, but the method is not called, i even tried to comment that code out so i am sure it never gets called but it doesnt help.

Comment: Yea my UI update methods are all invoked. I mean, i could handle exceptions that get thrown at me, but the application simply closes without visual studio showing me any error or exception.

Comment: Its also really strange that the application closes with exiting code 0, which signals everything is okay as far as i am informed.

Comment: I think it's important you show the method that calls ```private async Task ReceiveMessagesAsync()``` because in a couple of cases you ```break;``` from the ```while``` loop and fall out this method. Viewers of your question then don't know what happens. Your exception handling is logging internally in the application and not to a log file. It also issues a ```break;``` statement. So any exception handling and then a ```break;``` is going to exit your ```while``` loop. Depending on what happens on the caller side, determines whether your code falls through to an exit scenario.

Comment: I added the code that calls the method receiveMessagesAsync(), its at the very bottom of the new method i just added. Thank you for all your help so far.

Comment: Why are you calling that method with a 'discard' (```_```) ? This means the caller will not wait for your ```ReceiveMessageAsync()``` to complete. So your ```ConnectAsync()``` method will complete on its thread and return to its caller. Your ```ConnectAsync()``` method is already marked with ```async``` keyword, so may as well use ```await ReceiveMessagesAsync();``` instead of ```_ = ReceiveMessagesAsync();```. I think your caller threads are terminating early without error, but all created sub-threads they may have spawned will simply be terminated also, since their owning thread completes.

Comment: Also... review "Using await inside a discarded function" within this article: https://medium.com/codex/are-you-discarding-async-functions-correctly-405da846766d

Comment: oh okay thank you very much. I used the discard because VS gave me a warning and suggested to use a discard.. and i did without knowing what it even does... I removed the discard but that didnt solve my problem. I need to further think about what you wrote.

Comment: If you are now using an ```await``` instead of ```_``` discard, then your calling thread waits for your ```ReceiveMessageAsync()``` to complete. The latter will only exit the ```while``` loop when one of the ```break;``` statements are hit. That should tell you something informative. Either it's an exception occurring, or you've force-read the TcpClient/TcpListener and encountered zero bytes. This latter case makes sense if on the earlier loop iteration you read all that was in the buffer and nothing has been received since.

Comment: Lastly see here, where it contains "For connection-oriented sockets," https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.sockets.socket.receiveasync?view=net-7.0

Comment: I did try to comment out the two "break" statements to see if the problem is indeed in receivein zero bytes, but that is not the case. I also tried to set a breakpoint inside the if(amountBytes == 0) block, but i dont reach that block. I guess it really is a exception but i dont know how to catch that exception. I will now read the microsoft documentation you linked, maybe i find a solution there.

Comment: I would add file logger to your project. Log the start + end of each method before the final ```}``` or before any ```return``` statement, and also log any exception handling. You need to understand what is executing and when. It's not clear to me as I don't have the whole listing to see where/why your process terminates. Also, I looked at your Q for the threading aspects, but strangely never needed to use sockets myself (I've used .NET Remoting, Web Services, Web API). If you got an exit code of zero, that at least suggests you didn't have an exception (unless you consumed/handled it first).

Comment: You can also enable breaking on unhandled exceptions. Tools-->Options-->Debugger-->General--> Enable Just My Code. This will change your Debug--> Exceptions Dialog Box to show a checkbox for User-unhandled Errors.

Comment: I need to apologise for the earlier link. I drew your attention to a method override you are not using. I notice you use a byte array as a parameter, but that link does not show an override that accepts a byte array for .NET 7.0. I am wondering if this has something to do with your issue. Most of the examples use an ```ArraySegment``` and perhaps it is worth constructing one to use with ```_clientSocket.ReceiveAsync```

Comment: No apologises needed. You was the only one here that helped me, big props to you. I dont wanna praise the day before the morning, but it seems to work now. You wouldnt expect what the solution seems to be. Another form (lets call it selection form) opened the current form where my code is getting executed in the load method. I changed "this.close()" to "this.hide()", and now its working. I am not sure, but seems like the selection form closed and caused the application to stop. I dont know exactly why, but changing the "this." line did the trick. I will now test further to be sure its running.

Comment: That might happen if your processing threads were created from the selection form. Or if your selection form was your main form.  Glad you've made enough progress to not have the original issue. On the form thing, the MS docs detail what happens when a form closes: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.form.close?view=windowsdesktop-7.0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution, it was something clompletly else!

I am using win forms, and another form (which was the main form) called the current form where my code gets executed automaticaly by the load method when the new form sucesfully opened. I was using this.Close() on the previous form, so my new form was getting closed after a very short time, and i thought my code is causing this. I changed the line to this.Hide() and now it works. I guess its wise if i change it back to this.Close() and set the settings that the application shouldnt close when the mainForm closes, but instead if the last Form closes.